# SQL Server 2014 duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have 3 tables and I am trying to find the duplicates. There is a small condition that is throwing me off. These are the 3 tables

[image]

Now I need to run a query to get all institutions for `GroupID = 100` and also return any duplicate institutions based on the `InstitutionName`. So my result set should include both `InstitutionID = 1` and `2` since they are dupes on `Name` even though only one of them belongs to the group 100.

The query should not return data for `InstitutionID = 3` because it isn't a duplicate on `Name` even though it belongs to the Group 100.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. With that sample table data, what is the expected result. Can you also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using first two tables `institution` and `department` is enough, where use `in` operator and `exists` clause :

```
select *
  from institution
 where institutionname in 
      (
        select i.institutionname
          from institution i 
         where exists ( select 1 from department d where groupid = 100  ) 
         group by i.institutionname
         having count(i.institutionname)>1
      );

institutionid   institutionname deparmentid
1               ABC             123
2               ABC             456
```

**Edit :** *I think you want this as more(by using "group" table also) :*

```
with institution( institutionid, institutionname, deparmentid, city ) as
(
 select 1,'ABC',123,'New York' union all
 select 2,'ABC',456,'New York' union all
 select 3,'DEF',123,'Chicago'  union all
 select 4,'GHI',789,'Los Angeles'
),    
     department( deparmentid, deparmentname, groupid ) as
(
 select 123,'dept1',100 union all
 select 456,'dept2',101 union all
 select 789,'dept3',102 
),
     "group"( groupid, groupname ) as
(
 select 100,'Group A'     
)    
    select ii.*, g.groupname, dd.deparmentname
      from institution ii
      left join department dd on dd.deparmentid = ii.deparmentid
      left join "group" g on g.groupid = dd.groupid
     where ii.institutionname in 
          (
            select i.institutionname
              from institution i 
             where exists ( select 1 from department d where d.groupid = 100  ) 
             group by i.institutionname
             having count(i.institutionname)>1 and count(i.city)>1
          );

institutionid   institutionname deparmentid city      groupname deparmentname
1               ABC             123         New York  Group A   dept1
2               ABC             456         New York  NULL      dept2
```

Comment: This works great. What if there is another column City in the Institution Table and we need to match on both Name and City?

Comment: @JackSmith do you mean duplicate city name, too ?

Comment: Duplicate based on both Name and City. Also in the resultset how do we get the GroupName, DeptName, etc? Do we again do a join with the main outer Institution table with the Group and Department tables?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the names of institutions belonging in group = 100 and then with `in` get the rows from `institution`:

```
select * from institution
where name in (
  select i.name
  from institution i inner join department d
  on d.departmentid = i.departmentid
  inner join group g
  on g.groupid = d.groupid
  where g.groupid = 100
)
```